# Is it possible that the distribution of std::mt19937 gets "better" with some "unused generations"?

Tags: c++, random, montecarlo, mt19937

I'm developing a program for Monte Carlo integration and using std::mt19937 as the generator.

Sorry I cannot paste my code here, but it's something like:

```cpp
long long result = 0;
std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device()());
while (/*continue*/) {
    result += f(rng()); // do some calculation
    // for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) rng(); // unused generations
}
// some other calculations
```

With a fixed number of samples, the Monte Carlo estimation seems to be more accurate if I uncomment the "unused generations" line. Further, if I increase the number of unused generations (say 30 -> 50), error seems to get even lower.

The unused generations indeed change the internal state of generator, but is it possible to yield better distribution by doing this?

Changing the seed didn't change this phenomenon.

(I know my question is somehow vague) I'm wondering if anyone has similar experience.

Anything could be helpful. Thank you in advance!

### Update

As @JesperJuhl suggested, I've tried seeding `std::mt19937` with `std::seed_seq`. It looks like my generators were not properly seeded and because multiple generators are used in different threads, the poor seeding seems to have caused the "accuracy" problem.

`std::seed_seq` [in the cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq)
and [discussions on usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522829/how-to-properly-initialize-a-c11-stdseed-seq).

I'd thank everyone offering to help. I've learned a lot.

Comment: You are seeding the generator with just a single 32bit number. That's not enough to  fill it's entire internal state. Try using a `std::seed_seq` with enough data to seed all the internal state. Also look into using one of the available distributions to shape the raw random numbers.

Comment: I have seen the notion that "priming" the standard library PRNGs is effective. But I'd first try @JesperJuhl 's suggestions.

Comment: For a larger range of numbers there's also `std::mt19937_64`.

Comment: PRNG analysis can be very complicated, so what you suggest can't be ruled out by myself, but "skipping" a fixed number of steps between calls doesn't change the GF(2)-linear nature underlying the MT. So I doubt the result has a significantly different distribution. But this is just my hunch from glancing at it, not a true analysis.

Comment: Thank you guys. I've tried @JesperJuhl 's suggestions. It looks like my generator was not properly seeded and `std::seed_seq` did solve the problem (at least the error goes down). `std::mt19937_64` also brings some benefits on accuracy, but slows down the program.

Comment: If you are looking for a random seeding, and `std::random_device` is a good source of entropy on your system, you can use the short program I posted on GitHub to seed `std::mt19937`.  It works like a seed sequence, but uses `std::random_device` to generate the seeds. See the [discussion](https://github.com/tbxfreeware/seed_randomly/tree/main) and [source code](https://github.com/tbxfreeware/seed_randomly/blob/main/tbx.seed_randomly.cpp14.h) on GitHub.