# Efficiently generating random bytes of data in C++11/14

Tags: c++, c++11, random, distribution

My requirement is to generate random bytes of data *(not random numbers)* aka uniformly distributed bits.

As such I was wondering what are the correct/efficient ways of doing this using C++11/14 random facilities. I've had a look around at the examples, but they ***all*** seem to focus on number generation *(ints, floats etc)*

Current solution I'm using is the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>

int main()
{
   std::random_device rd;
   std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,255);
   std::vector<char> data(1000);
   for (char& d : data)
   {
      d = static_cast<char>(dist(rd) & 0xFF);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whats the difference between a random int, and four random btyes?

Comment: Nothing per say, so is the best way to generate 4 or 8 bytes at a time - and copy into the buffer 4/8 bytes per generation?

Comment: That's what I would do. Then there's no need for a `distribution` (which adds processing overhead).

Comment: ...and use the largest integral type available on the target platform.

Comment: @Cornstalks CaptainOblivious: I would like to use random_device directly, but the size of the return type seem to be implementation defined.

Comment: @soandos: Who's to say that `int` is four bytes?  The standard certainly doesn't.

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy, True, but not so material here. The point is random int = multiple random bytes

Comment: @Gerdiner: The size is implementation defined, but just use `sizeof()` to know how many bytes it is...

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy `int_least32_t`.

Comment: Also see [Why Aren't `std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t>` and `std::uniform_int_distribution<int8_t>` Allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31460733/1708801)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Distributions take random bits and turn them into numbers. If you actually want random bits then you want to use an engine:

> In particular, those requirements specify the algorithmic interface for types and objects that produce sequences of bits in which each possible bit value is uniformly likely.<sup>3</sup>
>
> A single call to a URNG object is allowed to produce and deliver many (typically 32 or more) bits, returning these bits as a single packaged value of an unsigned integer type.<sup>4</sup>
> [N3847](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3847.pdf)

`random_device` happens to be specified such that accessing uniformly distributed bits is easy:

```
std::random_device engine;
unsigned x = engine(); // sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT random bits
```

Note that other engines may not make it quite as easy to get uniformly random bits as `random_device`, due to returning fewer bits than their result_type can hold or even by effectively returning fractional bits.

If your concern is that `unsigned`'s size is implementation defined and so `random_device` returns an implementation defined number of bits, you can write an adapter that either collects enough bits before giving them to you, or one that will give you just enough bits and cache the rest for your next request. (You can also do this to handle other engines which exhibit the previously mentioned issues.)

Comment: The paper you quote is wrong (or at least misleading) on this point: URNGs are [not required](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#2327) to fill their output with random bits, so this answer is not correct. To take an extreme example, if `G::min() == 0` and `G::max == 2`, _none_ of the output bits will have an equal probability of being 1 or 0.

Real-life URNGs can and do take advantage of this license, so it is not safe to assume that you can get random bits from a URNG for exactly the reasons that are detailed in the paper you cite.

Comment: @GeoffRomer I suppose it's fair to say it's misleading; you can't just concatonate the integers returned from engines and treat the result like a bitstream. Engines with non-power of two ranges can be viewed simply returning fractional bits and in such cases recovering a random bit stream takes a bit more work. It's probably better to simply use an engine that does have a power of two range, as engines which don't, don't provide any particular advantage in return for imposing that cost.

Comment: @GeoffRomer It's also true that my answer is taking advantage of the fact that `random_device` is specified by C++ to fill its entire result value and not return any fractional bits, but I don't feel that there's anything unreasonable about such an implementation.

Comment: Fair enough, but your answer gives the strong impression that this will work for any URNG, not just `random_device`.

Answer (score 47):

What you're looking for is the [`std::independent_bits_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/independent_bits_engine) adaptor:

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using random_bytes_engine = std::independent_bits_engine<
    std::default_random_engine, CHAR_BIT, unsigned char>;

int main()
{
    random_bytes_engine rbe;
    std::vector<unsigned char> data(1000);
    std::generate(begin(data), end(data), std::ref(rbe));
}
```

Note that the accepted answer is not strictly correct in a general case – random engines produce unsigned values belonging to a range [`min()`, `max()`], which doesn't necessarily cover all possible values of the result type (for instance, `std::minstd_rand0::min() == 1`) and thus you may get random bytes that are not uniformly distributed if using an engine directly. However, for `std::random_device` the range is [`std::numeric_limits<result_type>::min()`, `std::numeric_limits<result_type>::max()`], so this particular engine would also work well without the adaptor.

Comment: Note: as @robert-allan-hennigan-leahy observed in another answer, `random_bytes_engine` doesn't technically support `unsigned char`, but this is probably a [defect in the standard](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2326).

Comment: What's a good way to seed std::independent_bits_engine<> from /dev/random?

Comment: @AndreasYankopolus - that's a good question which could standalone on SO.

Comment: Note that this is very inefficient. Independent bits engine will generate a new random for each byte, but the random it generates probably fills 32 or 64 bits, so this is 4 or 8x the required underlying rng engine calls. You'd basically have to reimplement independent_bits_engine in another form to do better, which is hard.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question: You can't.

The standard does not allow `std::uniform_int_distribution` to be templated on `char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char`.  Some believe that this is a defect in the standard, but it is the case.

You can simply template `std::uniform_int_distribution` on `unsigned short`, and set its min/max range to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()`, and then simply assign the result to an `unsigned char`.

From the standard:

> Throughout this subclause 26.5, the effect of instantiating a template:
>
> [...]
>
> e) that has a template type parameter named `IntType` is undefined unless the corresponding template argument is cv-unqualified and is one of `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`.
>
> §26.5.1.1 [rand.req.genl]

Moreover:

You should use [`std::mt19937`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) to actually generate your random bytes.  `std::random_device` is liable to be slow, and likely produces entropy with statistical properties (i.e. suitability for use in cryptography) that you don't need.

That said, you will need to seed your `std::mt19937`.  You can do this with a `std::random_device` and a [`std::seed_seq`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq).

Note that if you don't use a `std::seed_seq` to seed your `std::mt19937`, your `std::mt19937` will be left with many, many zeroes in its internal state, and it will therefore take it quite a while to "warm up".

For more information on "warm up", [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15509942/1007504).

Comment: I personally would have pointed out the undefined behavior and given Bryan time to fix it before downvoting, it was not an horrible answer, but that is just me.

Comment: [I'd like to see this defect fixed](https://isocpp.org/forums/iso-c-standard-discussion?place=msg%2Fstd-discussion%2FrOzm69RSNcg%2FaIqYf__XJb0J). Was it already reported/discussed somewhere?

Comment: This defect has been reported as [LWG 2326](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2326).

Comment: ... the new link to the [closed defect](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#2326). It was decided that it was a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to efficiency is to get the maximum number of values from every random number that is generated.  Here's a small tweak to your original code that does that.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

int main()
{
   std::random_device rd;
   std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> dist(0,0xFFFFFFFFu);
   std::vector<char> data(1000);
   int offset = 0;
   uint32_t bits = 0;
   for (char& d : data)
   {
      if (offset == 0)
         bits = dist(rd);
      d = static_cast<char>(bits & 0xFF);
      bits >>= 8;
      if (++offset >= 4)
         offset = 0;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If getting 4 bytes from every 32 bits doesn't work, try 3 bytes from 24 bits.

Answer (score -2):

Here's how I did it:

```
// Call srand(<some_number>) first if you want reproducible results
char oneRandomChar() {
    int x = rand();
    return (char) (x & 255);
}
```

As other folks have mentioned, you're drawing too sharp a distinction between a number and a byte. Of course it's true that you can interpret an int as a register and vice versa, but in hardware there is no distinction. This is one of those situations where you should focus on the benefits of being close to the metal. There's absolutely a time and place to build more specifics into the typing system (Haskell) but this is not one of them.