# Why are signed/unsigned 8-bit integer types not supported by C++ random number generation?

Tags: c++, random, std

From C++11 §26.5.1.1 on the requirements for random number generation:

> Throughout this subclause 26.5, the effect of instantiating a template: [...] that has a template type parameter named **IntType** is undefined unless the corresponding template argument is cv-unqualified and is one of short, int, long, long long, unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, or unsigned long long.

What is the reason that **8-bit** signed/unsigned types are excluded from random number generation like this in the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

This question was raised as [LWG Issue 2326](https://wg21.link/lwg2326), which was closed as "Not a Defect".

Not because people were not in favor, but because it was a new feature, instead of a bug. The committee felt that this would be better served by writing a paper discussing the advantages and disadvantages of making this change.

At present, no one has written such a paper.

As @NathanOliver notes, this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460733/why-arent-stduniform-int-distributionuint8-t-and-stduniform-int-distri) and the links there suggest that this is somewhat controversial.

Comment: Do you know why the restriction was included in the standard in the first place, though?

Comment: I do not.  It would take some research to find out. I got back to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1398.html, which has that restriction.