# Mersenne Twister seed as a member variable

Tags: c++, c++11, member-initialization

I want to know how to keep a mersenne random number generator as a member variable and use it in the same class.

I wrote the class as below and it works perfectly, but I do not like the that `std::mt19937` is initialized. I would like to know whether there is a way to initialize it in the constructor of `Test`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

class Test{
public:
    Test()
    {

    }
    void foo()
    {
        auto randomNum = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0, threads.size())(rnd);
    }

private:
    std::mt19937 rnd
    {
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()
    };
}
```

Comment: why do you want to do that? What is the problem with the current code? And what is the problem with moving the initialization to the constructor? Did you try something and it didnt work?

Comment: Are you looking for member init list? `Test() : rnd(seed) {...blah...}`.

Comment: Two ways: The first is to use the constructor initializer list to initialize the variable. This is basically equivalent to what you're doing now. The second way is to use the copy-assignment operator inside the constructor body to copy from a temporary object into the `m_random` object.

Comment: @Nathan, It is not a duplicate

Comment: @ HolyBlackCat Yes. But how do you do it with std::mt19937?

Comment: your code is `std::mt19937 rnd { seed };` and if you want to do that in the ctr, it should look like this `Test() : rnd( seed ) : {}`. However, afaik this will have identical effect

Comment: @tobi303 FYI, the first one doesn't prevent the class from being an aggregate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confused about exactly what a in class initialization does.  When you have

```
struct foo
{
    foo() {}
    int bar = 10;
};
```

That in class initialization is just syntactic sugar for

```
struct foo
{
    foo() : bar(10) {}
    int bar;
};
```

Whenever the compiler would add a member to a member initializer list (this is done when you forget it or when the compiler provides the constructor) it uses what you used in the initialization.  So with your code

```
class Test{
public:
    Test()
    {

    }
    void foo()
    {
        auto randomNum = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0, threads.size())(rnd);
    }

private:
    std::mt19937 rnd
    {
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()};
    };
};
```

Becomes

```
class Test{
public:
    Test() : rnd(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())
    {

    }
    void foo()
    {
        auto randomNum = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0, threads.size())(rnd);
    }

private:
    std::mt19937 rnd;
};
```

The nice thing about not actually doing it that way and using how you did it to begin with is you do not have to repeat

```
rnd(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())
```

in every constructor you write but you can always override it if you want something else for a specific constructor.

Comment: One smallthing. How would you use std::random_device in the above style with std::mt19937

Comment: @TharinduKumara If you wanted to do that then would write a function that does the initialization and returns the generator.  Then you can initialize the generator with that functions return.

Comment: @Nathanm, it can be used like this. `Test() : rnd(std::random_device{}()) {......}`.

Comment: @TharinduKumara Oh yes.  That way will work.  I though you were talking about initializing it like they do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509270/does-stdmt19937-require-warmup)