# Where is it better to store random_device/mt19937?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I have a function which makes use of randomness

```cpp
void fun() {
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<double> dis(0.0, 1.0);
    // ...
}
```

And, as I suspect, I'll get poor random if it's call repeatedly and both `rd` and `gen` are created each time. Is it better to make these variables global/private fields of a class so they are not redeclared multiple times?

Comment: Um, why don't you just do that?

Comment: You only need to store `mt19937`, since you only use `random_device` once during init.

Comment: Create the generator once in main, pass a reference to all the code that needs it. (Avoids the use of global variables/dependency injection).  You probably also want to do the same for the distribution, that also should not be recreated all the time.  You can also place both in a struct as members and pass that around (as a random context)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Could you explain how "passing a reference to the code that needs it" is different from dependency injection?

Comment: @wtz it is dependency injection :) I see now my text is a bit off :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A random number generator *should* be a global object. But there is nothing wrong with burying it in a function for access:

```
template <typename RealType>
RealType random_real_in_range( RealType min = 0., RealType max = 1. )
{
  thread_local std::mt19937 rng( std::random_device{}() );
  return std::uniform_real_distribution<RealType>( min, max )( rng );
}
```

The drawback here is that MT really should be “warmed up” by calling `.discard( 1000 )` or so...

Comment: [Does std::mt19937 require warmup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15509270/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random_device` to generate a seed to initialize `mt19937`. Since `random_device` is an expensive operation, no need to call it every time the function is called, and there's no need to save `random_device`.

`mt19937` is not thread safe. If your application is single-threaded, you can save it as a private data member of your class. However, if your application runs in multiple-thread, you'd better make it a thread local variable of the method.

```
void func() {
  thread_local mt19937(random_device{}());
}
```